# C++ determine if the software has not been opened on the same day (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, datetime, days

So I need to do some actions if the software has not been opened on the same day my plan is to store the number of days since the epoch for today's date in my database. Then when the software opens it will pull this number of days since the last epoch from the DB and then check that with today's number of days since the last epoch. Thus I will know if this is the same day or not.

I'm very inexperienced with C++ and I've been looking at the DateTime functions from "stdafx.h" however I've not been able to get the number of days since the last epoch.

So my goal in doing this would be to clear a database if this is the first time the software has been opened today. If it has already been opened today, then just continue on and do nothing.

I do not know how to go about this in C++. If it was python or C# or java I would have no trouble with this. So how would I go about this in C++?

Comment: The local clock might be wrong or purposely changed to bypass this verification.

Comment: Would you suggest a better way of achieving this then?

Comment: What's your end goal? What are the "some actions" that you want to perform? That's an important piece of information to include in the question.

Comment: I just want to clear a database if the software hasn't been opened today.

Comment: What DB engine are you using?  Most provide date functions.  For example SQLIte has https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: It's an Access database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 to [melak47's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31856979/576911).  I just wanted to add (and this wouldn't fit in a comment), that his answer assumes the day changes in the UTC timezone, which might just be fine.  This is a very good and efficient answer for many applications, including stack**overflow** itself!

But in case you want the day change to happen at *local* midnight, [here is a library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) that can help you do that, while still sticking with the nice `<chrono>` facilities.  Indeed this is just a very minor tweak to [melak47's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31856979/576911):

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;

    auto tp = system_clock::now();
    auto lp = current_zone()->to_local(tp);
    auto days_since_epoch = duration_cast<days>(lp.time_since_epoch());
    std::cout << days_since_epoch.count() << "\n";
}
```

It will give exactly the same answer as [melak47's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31856979/576911), except when the machine is set to a local timezone that differs from UTC, and UTC is currently already into the next day, or still on the previous day, compared to the local timezone.

Comment: Ahh, this would be more useful, as this could be ran across the world and thus it would be bad to reset this half way through the day in the far east for example.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `<chrono>` standard header, it's quite easy to get the number of days since the clock's epoch.
For example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using days = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<24 * 60 * 60>>;

    auto days_since_epoch = std::chrono::duration_cast<days>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());

    std::cout << days_since_epoch.count() << "\n";
}
```

I think the implementation is free to use whatever epoch, but if you only care about the difference in the number of days of successive calls, you should be fine.

Note that since we're essentially rounding down to the beginning of they day, 
if your user opens your application once at 23:59 and then again one minute later, you'll perceive a calendar day to have passed.

Comment: This `using` clause is glorious.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm a little stuck trying to compile this. What would you need in the header file? This is coming up with 6 errors for me. First one is: days_since_epoch cannot be used before it is initialized. I tried auto days_since_epoch; in the header file, but that doesn't work.

C++ is so weird when you're used to higher level languages, and not only that, it's so hard to read. Python reads like a poem half the time. This just reads like colons and arrows...

Another is: 'days' : symbol cannot be used in a using-decleration

Comment: What compiler (and version) are you using? You may need the -std=c++11 option (or a newer compiler :/)